# Load HTML content synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

I need to load HTML in a div.

```
$("#content").load("content.html");
$("#myText").html("Prasath");
```

After that I need to update some text in a `div(id='myText')` which is available in "content.html". "content.html" contains huge data, so it takes some time to load. Before that this line is executed:

```
$("#myText").html("Prasath");
```

How to load HTML content synchronously from JavaScript/jQuery ?
I don't want to do this from call back option in load.

Comment: I think in chrome browser gives you a warning on loading content synchronously. You should use a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#content").load("content.html", function(data){
    // this will execute after load is fired.
});
```

Use a callback.

EDIT: If you really want to make synchronous request, you can use the following code. However, you'll get a warning in console as I mentioned in the comment earlier:

```
var data = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "content.html",
        async: false
    }).responseText;
// this code waits for the above ajax request.
```

Comment: I know this call back option already. To explain my issue I gave that sample. Actually in my application I am not going to update any text. I need to make a call to the server, based on the response I need to update. Again my need is not to make a call from callback option in load.

Comment: In ajax, where should I mention div id "content" ?

Comment: You can do `$('#content').html(data)` after ajax call.

Answer (score 4):

You can't load it synchronously but you can quite easily do the next task in the `load()` callback. For example:

```
$("#content").load("content.html", function() {
    $("#myText").html("Prasath");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) about `load()`.

You can pass callback function to `load()`

**For example:**

```
$("#content").load("content.html", function(){
    $("#myText").html("Prasath");
});
```

**EDIT:** There is no way to make `load()` to load content synchronously. A workaround solution is that you can define a Jquery function that use [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send synchronous request to target url and then set the response content to destinate div.

```
$(function(){

  $.fn.extend({
      syncLoad: function (url) {

         var result = $.ajax({
          url: url,
          async: false,
          type: "GET"
         }).responseText;

         $(this).html(result);

      }
  });

  $("#content").syncLoad("/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!");

});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1v8fmb8b/